# Can someone explain me this code

Tags: java, division, roman-numerals

I need an explanation for this tiny java code.

`decimalNumber` is a variable for user input and M for roman numeral 1000
This is a part of a roman numeral converter:

```
m = decimalNumber / 1000;
decimalNumber = decimalNumber % 1000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line `m = decimalNumber / 1000;` sets `m` equal to the number of thousands in `decimalNumber.`

Then, the second line, sets `decimalNumber` equal to `decimalNumber mod 1000`. (If you're unfamiliar with modulo, it's the remainder after division.)

So, for example, let's take the number `2453` to start with in `decimalNumber`. First, we set `m` equal to `2453 / 1000` which, in integer division, is `2`. (Remember, the remainder is lost when dividing integers, but NOT when dividing floats.)

Then, `decimalNumber` is set equal to `2453 % 1000`, which is `453`.

By doing this, you're basically counting how many 'M's you need in your final number, then reducing `decimalNumber` by that many thousands.

Answer (score 3):

The `/` operator between two `int`s performs an [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers) - i.e., it returns only the whole part of the division. The `%` operator is the modulo operator - it returns the remainder of the division.

So here, you use `/` to get the thousands part of the number, and then assign the remainder to it, presumably to continue the conversion of hundreds, tens, etc.

Comment: So if the decimal number is 1500 m= 1500/1000 = 1,5?

Comment: @F.Pajic then `m = 1` and `decimalNumber = 500`. `decimalNumber` is an int, yes? Not a float or double?

Comment: Why 1 ? When 1500/1000 = 1,5

Comment: @F.Pajic As noted, if `decimalNumber` is an `int`, you'll be performing integer division, and only get the whole part (the part left of the decimal point).